# PHP script that can extract text between multiple title tags of certain website?

Tags: php, extract

Hello I found few and tried few, but nothing really works for me. Best I found was able to extract title of the page, but there are many title tags on the page and it extracted only the first one. I need it to extract all titles. If it also could 
It is this code:

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");
if (preg_match('~<title[^>]*>(.*?)</title>~si', $text, $body)){
echo $body[1];
}

?>
```

Comment: No website should have more than 1 <title> tag... unless it's XML with a XSLT maybe; in which case, `DOMDocument` and `getElementsByTagName()` might be best : http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution

```
$text = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");
preg_match_all('/<title>.*?<\/title>/is', $text, $matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $m)
{
    echo htmlentities($m)."<br />";
}
```

For example:

```
// input text
$text = <<<EOT
<title>Lorem ipsum dolor</title>
sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim <title>ad minim</title> veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip <title>ex ea</title> commodo consequat.
EOT;

// solution
preg_match_all('/<title>(.+?)<\/title>/is', $text, $matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $m)
{
    echo htmlentities($m)."<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
<title>Lorem ipsum dolor</title>
<title>ad minim</title>
<title>ex ea</title>
```

**POST UPDATED (to reflect the changes in the question).**

For example you want to load some "a.html" file:

```
<html>
<body>
Lorem ipsum dolor
<a title="Ravellavegas.com Analysis" href="http://somewebsite.com/" />
sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
<a title="Articlesiteslist.com Analysis" href="http://someanotherwebsite.com/" />
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</body>
</html>
```

Then, you have to write the script as follows:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('a.html');

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag) {
    echo $tag->getAttribute('title').'<br/>';
}

?>
```

This outputs:

```
Ravellavegas.com Analysis
Articlesiteslist.com Analysis
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all), it'll give you an array of matches and you can then work with each one.

Answer (score 0):

If it's HTML there should only be 1  tag... but, granted, it could be XML with an XSLT. In which case, instead of mucking about with RegExps to attempt to parse it, it's generally better to create a DOMDocument object and use that instead:

Of course, if the document isn't XML well formed this is going to fall over.

```
//taken directly from the comments on PHP documentation at : 
//  http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php
//  so that you can load in an XML file over HTTP

$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'PHP libxml agent',
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
libxml_set_streams_context($context);

// request a file through HTTP
$xml = DOMDocument::load('http://www.example.com/file.xml');


// added this bit to get the <title> elements
$aTitles = $xml->getElementsByTagName('title');

//  loop and output
foreach($aTitles as $oTitle) {
  echo "<p>{$oTitle->nodeValue}</p>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I have made big mistake, I do not need title tag, it is something different. In code of site the part of html looks like this:

```
<td><a title="Ravellavegas.com Analysis" href="http://www.statscrop.com/www/ravellavegas.com">
```

From it I need to exctract only the webadress, so from this, only ravellavegas.com

Comment: I've made an update to my previous answer to reflect the changes in Your question.